# I get false lat long for the cities of Dom-Tom when i use geocoder google

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, google-geocoder

my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ....
//....

var adresse = jQuery.trim(region) + ", " +jQuery.trim(adresse) + ", " + jQuery.trim(codePostal) + ", " + jQuery.trim(ville) + ", " +  jQuery.trim(pays);

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                    geocoder.geocode({ address: adresse, region: 'no' },
                    function (coords, status) {
                         if (status.toLowerCase() == 'ok') {
                                var lat = coords[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                var lon = coords[0].geometry.location.lng();    
                                console.log("lat :"+lat+",  lon :"+lon);

                         }
                         else {
                            alert("address not found");
                         }
                    } );

</scrip>
```

I have a problem latlong the region dom-tom of France, I have latlong false when I insert this address
"La Réunion, 9 Rue des Poivriers, 97400, Saint-Denis, France"
I like latlong => (lat: 48.936181, lon: 2.3574429999999893) but it's false

I hope someone has a solution, if so thank you for helping me
(Sorry about my english!)

Comment: how false? how many meters, kilomters?

Comment: It's not a problem with meters or kilometers ... but I have latitude and longitude it's not correspond to my address "Réunion, 9 Rue des Poivriers, 97400, Saint-Denis, France"
(thank you for the time you gave to answer)

Comment: that was my question: measure the distance between the wrong lat,long and the correct lat,long.

Comment: you can see my screenshot http://screencast.com/t/9ZQ9gkgsnmq

Total Distance : 5829.125 and
latitude and longitude exact : -20.88 , 55.45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally just eliminate the country for overseas regions
like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ....
//....

if(jQuery.trim(pays) == 'France'){
var adresse = jQuery.trim(region) + ", " +jQuery.trim(adresse) + ", " + jQuery.trim(codePostal) + ", " + jQuery.trim(ville);
}
else{
var adresse = jQuery.trim(region) + ", " +jQuery.trim(adresse) + ", " + jQuery.trim(codePostal) + ", " + jQuery.trim(ville) + ", " +  jQuery.trim(pays);
}

//...

</script>
```

Thanks you a lot  AlexWien